# Default value for a Handlebars` template placeholder

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, template-engine

Can I specify a default value for a Handlebars` template placeholder?

```
<script type="x-handlebars-template" id="menu-edit-form-tpl">
    <form method="{{method}}" action="{{action}}" class="menu-edit-form">
...                     
    </form>
</script>
```

Can I specify default values for {{method}} and {{action}} and skip them in the object that is passed to the compiled template?

Comment: If you have other various handlebars helper needs, there's a big library of helper functions here: https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#default - you can use it as `require('handlebars-helpers')({ handlebars });` and then `{{default method 'POST'}}`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Handlebars has no "default values".
You should use `{{#if}}` statement to check property is set.

```
<script type="x-handlebars-template" id="menu-edit-form-tpl">
    <form method="{{#if method}}{{method}}{{else}}POST{{/if}}" action="{{#if action}}{{action}}{{else}}/{{/if}}" class="menu-edit-form">
...
    </form>
</script>
```

Or if you want a bit cleaner syntax, use the simple helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('safeVal', function (value, safeValue) {
    var out = value || safeValue;
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(out);
});
```

which allows you to write like this:

```
<script type="x-handlebars-template" id="menu-edit-form-tpl">
    <form method="{{safeVal method 'POST'}}" action="{{safeVal action '/'}}" class="menu-edit-form">
...
    </form>
</script>
```

Comment: For me it only works when if write `{{#if}}` instead of `{{if}}` (I'm using metalsmith)

Comment: Another option is to use or from ember truth helpers, giving the syntax of:

{{or method 'POST'}}

Using the ember truth helpers from: 
https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers

Comment: That's why I hate Handlebars... you are forced to create 'a simple helper' for something that it's BUILT IN in JS. In JSX {a || b} JustWorks.

Answer (score 9):

**Here is my simple solution**

first we create a very basic helper called 'choose'

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('choose', function (a, b) {return a ? a : b;});
```

then we use it in the template :)

```
<p>
{{choose valueFromData 'default-value-in-template'}}
<p>
```

or of course we can do

```
    <p>
    {{choose valueFromData defaultValueFromData}}
    <p>
```

So in your case:

```
<form method="{{choose method 'get'}}" action="{{choose action 'action.php'}}" class="menu-edit-form">
...                     
    </form>
```

Hope it helps someone else since this is from 2014 :)

Answer (score 7):

This question and its accepted answer are quite old and a lot of new features and functionality have been added to handlebars since they were written.

I managed to get the functionality of default values by using [partial blocks](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/1076) which were released in v4.0.0 - so your template would end up looking like this:

```
<script type="x-handlebars-template" id="menu-edit-form-tpl">
    <form method="{{#> method}}get{{/method}}" action="{{#> action}}index.php{{/action}}" class="menu-edit-form">
...                     
    </form>
</script>
```

Then it's just a case of passing in your `method` and `action` as partials by doing something like this:

```
var source = $('#menu-edit-form-tpl').html(),
    template = Handlebars.compile(source),
    html = template({}, {
        partials: {
            action: 'contact-form.php'
        }
    });
```

In the resulting html the method will default to `get` and the action will be `contact-form.php`. Here's a working demo:

```js
var source = $('#menu-edit-form-tpl').html(),
    template = Handlebars.compile(source),
    html = template({}, {
        partials: {
            action: 'contact-form.php'
        }
    });


// Code below here only to show output.
document.write('<code>' + $("<div/>").text(html).html() + '</code>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="x-handlebars-template" id="menu-edit-form-tpl">
    <form method="{{#> method}}get{{/method}}" action="{{#> action}}index.php{{/action}}" class="menu-edit-form">
        ...
    </form>
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can register a `helperMissing` helper which will get called whenever a value is defined in your template, but not in your context (useful if you don't want missing values to fail silently):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("helperMissing", function(context, options) {
    console.error("Template defines {{" + context.name + "}}, but not provided in context");
    return "{{" + context.name + "}}";
});
```